# R: Applying function to DataFrame

Tags: r, list, function

I have following code:

```
library(Ecdat)
data(Fair)
Fair[1:5,]

x1 = function(x){
  mu = mean(x)
  l1 = list(s1=table(x),std=sd(x))
  return(list(l1,mu))
}

mylist <- as.list(Fair$occupation,
               Fair$education)

x1(mylist)
```

What I wanted is that x1 outputs the result for the items selected in mylist. However, I get `In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`.

Comment: Please check the `str` of the `mylist`.  If it is a `list`, loop through the list elements and apply the function ie. `lapply(mylist, x1)`  Also, I think the `as.list` is not doing what you intended as it splits into a `list` of length 601 with 1 element each.  Perhaps you just need `lapply(Fair[c("occupation", "education")], x1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lapply if your passing a list to a function

```
output<-lapply(mylist,FUN=x1)
```

This will process your function x1 for each element in mylist and return a list of results to output.

Answer (score 0):

Here the `mylist` is created not in the correct way and a `list` is not needed also as `data.frame` is a `list` with columns of equal length.  So, just subset the columns of interest and apply the function

```
lapply(Fair[c("occupation", "education")], x1)
```

---

In the OP's code, `as.list` simply creates a `list` of `length` 601 with only a single element in each.

```
str(mylist)
#List of 601
#$ : int 7
#$ : int 6
#$ : int 1
#...
#...
```

Another problem in the code is that it is not even considering the 2nd argument.  Using a simple example

```
as.list(1:3, 1:2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 3
```

The second argument is not at all considered.  It could have been

```
list(1:3, 1:2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2
```

But for data.frame columns, we don't need to explicitly call the `list` as it is a `list` of `vectors` that have equal length.

Regarding the error in OP's post, `mean` works on `vector`s and not on `list` or `data.frame`.